# How do I use a row value as a variable to refer to an address in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell that uses match function to find the location from a column and I want to use that location value to refer to another column.

For example:

- cell G1 stores the value *49* from the function `Match(223, D:D, 0)`
- G2  will refer to column E and use the value from G1 for row
- so G2 should return E49. If the value of G1 was *55* G2 would be E52.

How would i do that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what u need is a INDIRECT function. Try this in cell G2: `=INDIRECT("E"&G1)`

Comment: Yes that worked like a charm. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could try is an `INDIRECT` function.

Try this in cell G2:
 `=INDIRECT("E"&G1)`

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX` would be a better method - `INDIRECT` is volatile, while `INDEX` isn't.
`=INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(223,$D:$D, 0))` or `=INDEX($E:$E,$G$1)` (return a reference to the 49th row in column E).

http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/